# Accessing script content with cheerio

Tags: node.js, web, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm using Cheerio and request with Node.js to do some basic web scraping, but can't seem to figure out how to access the data. The page loads via request and I'm able to console.log the page title using Cheerio, but when I get to the scripts it's a complex mess of objects.

In the body section of the page it looks like..

```
<body> 
  <script src="someUrl" script type="text/javascript" /> 
  <script src="someUrl" script type="text/javascript" /> 
  <script src="someUrl" script type="text/javascript" />
  <script type="text/javascript">var months = [6,12,24,36,48,60]; var amounts = [5000,10000,15000,20000,25000]</script>
```

I'm trying to get to the variables in the last script to store them as variables in my node script for use, but I can't seem to access them, even as text.

When I try this in node, I get the page title followed by some huge object response in the console, not the variable text to parse.  Suggestions?

```
$ = cheerio.load(body);
console.log($('title').text());
var text = $('script');
console.dir(text[3]);
```

Comment: `cheerio` parses the HTML and creates a mini-DOM that you can access.  It does not parse and run the Javascript in the page.  To do that, you would need what is often called a head-less browser such as PhantomJS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can parse those variables with regex but cheerio is a little messy:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio')
var html = `
<body>
  <script src="someUrl" type="text/javascript" />
  <script src="someUrl" type="text/javascript" />
  <script src="someUrl" type="text/javascript" />
  <script type="text/javascript">var months = [6,12,24,36,48,60]; var amounts = [5000,10000,15000,20000,25000]</script>
</body>
`
var str, $ = cheerio.load(html, {xmlMode: true}); // xmlMode: true is a workaround for many cheerio bugs.
console.log(str = $('script:not([src])')[0].children[0].data) // no cleaner way to do this, cheerio?
// var months = [6,12,24,36,48,60]; var amounts = [5000,10000,15000,20000,25000]

var months = JSON.parse(str.match(/months = (\[.*?\])/)[1])
console.log(months)
// [ 6, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60 ]

var amounts = JSON.parse(str.match(/amounts = (\[.*?\])/)[1])
console.log(amounts)
// [ 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000 ]
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much!